# Capacitor - Uncaught TypeError: cap.[some_function] is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I just upgraded capacitor to 3.2.x and when I try to build my Ionic project, almost no capacitor function seems to work. For example, I get errors like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cap.nativeCallback is not a function
...
Uncaught TypeError: Capacitor.createEvent is not a function
...
package com.getcapacitor.annotation does not exist
```

Here's my Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.17.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.2.3
   @capacitor/android : 3.0.0-beta.3
   @capacitor/core    : 3.2.3
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.1

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/che-azeh/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.21.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 7.5.2
   OS                : Linux 5.11
```

Answer (score 1):

Here was the problem: if you look at the **capacitor** section under my **Ionic Info**, you'd notice an incosistency between Capacitor CLI, @capaciotr/core and @capacitor/android:

```
Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.2.3
   @capacitor/android : 3.0.0-beta.3
   @capacitor/core    : 3.2.3
```

So what I did was upgrade all 3 to their latest versions:

```
npm install @capacitor/cli@latest @capacitor/core@latest
npm install @capacitor/android@latest
```

Now, it looks ike:

```
Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.2.3
   @capacitor/android : 3.2.3
   @capacitor/core    : 3.2.3
```

Finally, I remove the Android folder created by capacitor (`rm -R ./android`), reinitialize capacitor (`npx cap init`) rebuild ionic project (`ionic build android`) and then `npx cap add android`.
And solved! Zero errors!